# Ag-Grid : Access to the row node/data in the browser's Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

When debugging my application with Chrome's Developer Tools I would like to be able to access the row `node` or the column on a given `ag-cell`.

I can do it if there is an Angular `cellRenderer` (using `ng.getComponent($0)` I can access my Angular component and the `params`). But is it possible with the default `cellRenderer` ?

Comment: so what you'd like is to get the row node data in dev tools when you click on a row?

Comment: yes or calling a function with $0 in the dev tool's console, like we do for ng.getComponent($0)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a simple solution: use the `cellClicked` callback.

```
(cellClicked)="cellClicked($event)"
```

and in your component:

```
cellClicked(params)
{
    console.log(params.node)
}
```

I've created a StackBlitz for your [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-oaye2v).

Comment: Thanks, it's an option, but I was hopping something were I do not have to modify/recompile the code each time. I will try to create a function extracting the information I need

Comment: I don't think using `ng.getComponent($0)` will be possible due to the way the grid is created.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer works only if you are using AgGrid within Angular.**

I created a function (here in Typescript) that can be included in your app code.

You can then call-it from the Dev Tools:

- select an element inside the AgGrid (which must be created using an  Angular Component)
- in the console, run `getAgGridCellInfo($0)`    (as you would call `ng.getComponent($0)`)

Code to be copied inside your app's code :

```
/**
 * For Dev tool's console, provides an easy access to a cell's Node and column.
 * Just :
 *  * select an element inside the AgGrid (which must be created using an <ag-grid-angular> Angular Component)
 *  * in the console, run getAgGridCellInfo($0)    (as you would call ng.getComponent($0))
 *
 * @param element HTMLElement ($0 usually)
 * @return an object with some information on the row, column and cell
 */
function getAgGridCellInfo(element: HTMLElement) {
  if (!element) {
    console.error('Call with $0 parameter, after selecting a DOM element inside an AgGrid');
    return;
  }

  function getInheritedAttribute(el: HTMLElement, attributeName: string) {
    if (!el) {
      throw new Error('Could not find attribute ' + attributeName + ' in parents of ' + element);
    }
    const elVal = el.getAttribute(attributeName);
    return elVal != null ? elVal : getInheritedAttribute(el.parentElement, attributeName);
  }

  function getAgGridCompontent(el: HTMLElement) {
    const comp = window['ng'].getComponent(el);
    return comp && comp.constructor.name === 'AgGridAngular' ? comp : getAgGridCompontent(el.parentElement);
  }

  const rowId = getInheritedAttribute(element, 'row-id');
  const colId = getInheritedAttribute(element, 'col-id');
  const agGridComp = getAgGridCompontent(element);
  const api: GridApi = agGridComp?.api;
  const rowNode = api?.getRowNode(rowId);
  const colDef = api?.getColumnDef(colId);
  const value = colDef && rowNode && api.getValue(colId, rowNode);
  return {
    api: api,
    rowId: rowId,
    colId: colId,
    rowNode: rowNode,
    colDef: colDef,
    value: value,
    data: rowNode?.data
  };
}

window['getAgGridCellInfo'] = getAgGridCellInfo;
```